# Is it ok to store all unique IP addresses in a SQLite DB, or is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm just now learning Ruby on Rails, and I'm also new to SQLite.  The purpose of this question is purely educational. I understand that Google Analytics and other services can accomplish this, I'm just wondering how it would be done in Ruby on Rails.

I have a small website, that's basically a fake store (once again, for learning purposes).  Currently my database looks like this

```
| index | item | added_at | updated_at | description | total_clicks | unique_clicks |
```

The `item`, is an item for sale, `added_at` is the date the item was added to the store, `updated_at` is the date something changed about the item, like the `description`, which is a description of the item, and `total_clicks` is the total times the item is clicked (or viewed)

All of that is working, but I want to add some more, and I wasn't sure how to handle unique visitors.

Every time someone clicks on an item, I want to increment my `total_clicks`, but I also want to increment my `unique_clicks` if the visitor is unique.

I know that I can track the IP's by using `request.remoteip`, but how do I track if something is unique?  Is it a bad idea to store unique IP's in a database?  Would I just have one column that contained each IP address, and check that before incrementing?

Comment: How accurate do you want to be? This is a wide field. Companies try a lot to indentify uniq visits. Starting with simple cookies, then super cookies, browser fingerprinting and so on. An IP is not uniq. Most providers give there customers dynamic IP's. Or customers use proxy servers and so on.

Comment: I want the most basic way possible in RoR.  This is just me testing out things to do in the language.  Basically, if I can click a button on the site from two different computers on a network, and it reports two unique IP's...I'm happy (assuming that the site is in the house, and not going externally at all)

Comment: If it doesn't need to be an IP I would suggest a permanent cookie `cookies.permanent[:visit_counted] = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must store the addresses somehow to determine its uniqueness.
I would go one step further and store all accesses with their timestamps and addresses in its own table; they could be easily aggregated using SQL statements.

However, while IP tracking is a rather simple process, visitor tracking has a much more difficult science than that. There are many reasons you cannot simply map unique IP addresses to unique visitors. (Network address translators, dynamic IPs, user logging in from different devices, multiple users using the same device, etc.) Modern, sophisticated visitor tracking methods combine IP tracking, cookie analysis, among many other ideas.